# How does cursor know when to change shape/type - java

Tags: java, cursor, shapes

How does the cursor in Windows(Microsoft) know not only from the internet but on any application that it is looking at an image, link, or text in order to change shapes from arrow to hand or i-beam? Is there any way I can implement this function in my java application? Also does the cursor in Macbooks change shape like the Windows OS ones(never used a macbook...)?

Comment: At the very base, the UI monitors the most position, when the mouse moves into a "component", the component can instruct the OS to update the mouse pointer. How this is achieved will greatly depend on the API you are using. For example, in Swing, the components have a `set/getCursor` method

Comment: So, the Windows OS itself cannot detect if the cursor is pointing at an image, text, or a button?

Comment: No, it's the programs which control it

Comment: Is there any way then I could detect them(hyperlinks, images, texts) without clicking every single one?